Old El Paso Whole Green Chiles - No Water in Can
I have a can of Old El Paso Whole Green Chiles labeled Net Wt 4 oz. which is between 1 and 10 years old (don't remember buying it).  The second ingredient on the label is water, but when I shake the can it sounds like dried chiles only.  Almost opened it yesterday just to see but for now keeping it as a curio.
No holes, no external discoloration, the label is intact and it's been stored in a cupboard since purchase.
The stamp on the top of the can says:
12B011 then on the next line
AE 1455
Canning error?  Labeling error?  My error?  Thanks in advance for any info.

Is there any discoloration on the bottom of the can?  I once had a very old can develop a small leak and dry out like you mentioned.  The hole was difficult to see, as it had rusted or something.

No way to tell without physically having the can itself and having a look at the contents. You could presumably measure the weight of a similar empty can to get a bseline and compare with the weight of your can. Measurement of dimensions would give you volume and hence a measure of how heavy it should be if full with water. Have you tried to contact Old El Paso manufacturer?

@bob1 it may have a total contents weight and a drained weight. Beans, for example, do here

"Net Wt 4 Oz."  If I weighed it myself I wouldn't say "Net Wt" because l would only know the gross weight.  I can darn sure tell by hand that it's not 4 oz.

Assuming there isn't a readable "best by" date on the other end of the can (or somewhere) the codes suggest production in 2011, 2012, or 2014 at the latest. so it's more curio than food anyway. I also suspect a rust-through leak given lightness and advanced age.

@JudasHeimlich for things tinned in water (or brine, oil) I'm used to seeing 2 weights like this. It's a shame you don't have the same.  The labelling (assuming it's this product) is very odd - 3 servings per can, serving size 35g, or 1/3 of the net weight per serving - so not meant to be drained.  The outside dimensions work out to about 180ml so I'd be surprised if you could cram 113g of chillies in there plus some water.

Rust is normally visible along the bottom rim if a steel can has leaked, but I still think that's the case.  Personally I'd either open it and weigh the contents, or weigh it unopened, compare to a similar can and work out the contents weight.  I'd eat tinned stuff that old if it wasn't damaged
